# Enlarging APFS OS Volume - Unknown partition scheme

Tags: high-sierra, partition, apfs, dual-boot

I have my OSX install on a seperate AFPS partion, my home folder on another (HFS). In order to enlarge it I deleted a Linux partition following it, and now I get an error that it is not an AFPS device when I try to enlarge it. Given some other users problems with rebooting when they have this unknown partition I'm wondering if I should be concerned. The output of diskutil list follows:

```
Last login: Thu Mar 19 15:22:12 on ttys000
User-MBP:~ username$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               51.7 GB    disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                47.8 GB    disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                900.0 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +51.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume OS                      39.6 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
```

Here is the output of `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size`:

```
User-MBP:etc username$ diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size
   Partition Offset:         209735680 Bytes (409640 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                51.7 GB (51722964992 Bytes) (exactly 101021416 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
```

Comment: If it is still possible, add the output from the command `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size` to your question.

Comment: Is `disk0s4` the partition you want to remove? is `disk0s3` the partition you want to enlarge?

Comment: I am running out of room for the OS, on disk0s2, so is the one I want to enlarge. Disk0s3 was formerly a Linux partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot to macOS Recovery. Instructions for booting to macOS Recovery over the internet can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). Once booted to macOS Recovery, open a Terminal application window and enter the following commands.

```
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 101021416 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

After booting back to macOS, the commands given below will add the space formally used by linux to the partition where macOS is installed.

```
diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: I realized this is not the first time I have had this issue. The first time I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065640/recover-macbook-apfs-partition